# Heroku Collectstatic Timeout with Django App

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3, static-files

Having an unexpected issue where my latest attempts to run collectstatic for an app on Heroku times out indefinitely:

```
Running `python manage.py collectstatic` attached to terminal... up, run.6250
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dotenv.py:16: UserWarning: not reading .env -   it doesn't exist.
warnings.warn("not reading %s - it doesn't exist." % dotenv)

You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings.

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
```

After I enter "yes" it hangs and times out with no err. Same thing happens when I append --dry-run --noinput. My env.txt files includes

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
```

I'm puzzled because nothing changed in my code, and I've successfully run a collectstatic with this app previously.

App is using use django-storage over S3-boto. Here's my settings:

```
if DEBUG:
    #dev storage using local
    ...

else:
    # Production AWS S3    
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
    AVATAR_STORAGE_DIR = 'avatars/'

    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = env('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
    AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = env('AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH', False)
    AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = True

    STATIC_URL = 'http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
    MEDIA_URL = STATIC_URL
    ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'
```

All the AWS credentials are set in Heroku config. FWIW I have

```
heroku labs:enable user-env-compile
```

enabled

Answer (score 0):

Add `collectfast` to your requirements.txt file and settings.py (and check the [installation docs](https://github.com/antonagestam/collectfast/#installation)). It's a lifesaver especially if you have a lot of files, as it uses your caching setup to store hashes of the files that were previously uploaded. Adding this to a number of my Django projects has dramatically improved the static file collection (and in Heroku's case, actually made it workable).